# Handle Skipped Field in Regex

Tags: regex

How do we handle a missing field in regular expression?

I have following strings but some have missing Id ... i want my regex to read Id where it is present however ignore where this field isn't present. How to go about it? Any suggestions?

```
SessionId":1500000055031,"Id":235596,"Te":"XXnt",
SessionId":1500000055031,"Id":235596,"Te":"XXnt",
"SessionId":1500000055032,"Te":"CreateEreTree",
"SessionId":1500000055032,"Te":"CreateEreTree",
"SessionId":1500000055032,"Te":"CreateEreTree",
SessionId":1500000055031,"Id":235596,"Te":"XXnt",
SessionId":1500000055031,"Id":235596,"Te":"XXnt",
SessionId":1500000055031,"Id":235596,"Te":"XXnt",
SessionId":1500000055031,"Id":235596,"Te":"XXnt",
```

Below is the regex that I'm currently stucked at.

```
\w*":(\d*)."\w*":(\d*),"\w*":"(\w*)",
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to *do*? This looks suspiciously like an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem); a regex may very well not be the best way to achieve your goal, but if you only ask for help with the regex, you'll never discover the better way.

Answer (score 0):

Use lookaheads

```
(?=.*"\bId\b"\s*:\s*\d+)^.*$
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hL0uY6/1)**

Assuming `"` can be present or absent and there is only 6 digits present in your `ID` as it seems from your input, this will be

```
(?=.*"?\bId\b"?\s*:\s*\d{6}[^\d])^.*$
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hL0uY6/2)**

Answer (score 0):

Well, just fixing your regex. you can use optional construct `?` to capture if it exists and ignore otherwise.

```
\w*":(\d*).(?:"\w*":(\d*),)?"\w*":"(\w*)",
```